# C++ strings why cant be used as char arrays?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{    
    string a;

    a[0] = '1';
    a[1] = '2';
    a[2] = '\0';

    cout << a;
}
```

Why doesn't this code work? Why is it not printing the string?

Comment: `a` is empty. Therefore, undefined behaviour for writing to anything past what `capacity()` returns.

Comment: A string uses a character array under the hood. But as chris said, it's currently empty, this what you're doing is undefined. It would be much easier to do `string a = "12";`

Comment: There's actually no guarantee that std::string simply uses a char array under the hood is there? The only guarantee is that std::strng.c_str() will return one.

Comment: @Troy, It has to have a `char *`, doesn't it? I think that also has to be null-terminated as of C++11.

Comment: That's possible but to my knowledge at least some of them do. I guess I should have been more careful with my wording.

Comment: If you need to use `std::string` as a C-style string, you have that option using `c_str()` which returns a const pointer to a char array.

Comment: std::string is mysterious indeed. With all the conflicting answers and comments on this question ;)

Comment: @chris - Sorry, I meant for assignment, but even that was incorrect.  I stand corrected.  I will edit my comment.

Comment: @Troy, True, I might be a bit naive of the underlying implementation. The other thing is that it's different from languages such as C# and Java, where strings are immutable.

Comment: @Troy: It actually does have to use a `char*`. Why? Because (in C++11) a) the buffer must be contiguous, and b) `c_str()` must run in constant time.

Comment: @chris writes "*undefined behaviour for writing anything past what `capacity()` returns*". I believe it is undefined to write past `.size()`, even if you're still within `.capacity()`.

Comment: @Robᵩ, You're correct. I realized the last part doesn't even make sense. For example, why should it have the logic to readjust the null every time you access an element with what's supposed to be the efficient way. Also, I did look up one of the functions, and it mentioned that changing `str[str.size()]` is UB.

Comment: @chris: AFIU, `std::string` doesn't have to make the internal string null-terminating (except when `c_str()` is called) (not that this really matters, given yours and Robᵩ's last two comments)

Comment: @Cornstalks, I'm pretty sure that was the case in C++03 and changed in C++11. I know `data()` and `c_str()` do the same thing now.

Answer (score 7):

Because `a` is empty. You get the same problem if you try to do that same thing with an empty array. You need to give it some size:

```
a.resize(5); // Now a is 5 chars long, and you can set them however you want
```

Alternatively, you can set the size when you instantiate `a`:

```
std::string a(5, ' '); // Now there are 5 spaces, and you can use operator[] to overwrite them
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you mean `std::string`.

Second, Your string is empty.

Third, while you can use the operator[] to change an element in a string, you cannot use it to insert an element where none exists:

```
std::string a = "12";
a[0] = '3'; //a is now "32"
a[2] = '4'; //doesn't work
```

In order to do so, you need to make sure your string has allocated enough memory first. Therfore,

```
std::string a = "12";
a[0] = '3'; //a is now "32"
a.resize(3); //a is still "32"
a[2] = '4'; //a is now "324"
```

Fourth, what you probably want is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{    
    std::string a = "12";    
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `operator[]` to add characters to a string is not supported. There are a variety of reasons why this is the case, but one of them is this:

```
string a;
a[1] = 12;
```

What should `a[0]` be?

Comment: This is only if the space isn't already allocated, which is the same for c-strings. Use std::string.resize first and you can add(?) characters all you like.

Comment: @Troy: I think you're using a different definition of add.  What you call 'adding', I (and I'm sure David) would call 'changing'.  If you resized, the characters were already added.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a string is an object, not an array. Try:

```
string a = "12";
cout << a;
```

If you like, you can still use old-style C-strings, so:

```
char a[3];
a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '2';
a[2] = '\0';
...
```

What you're trying to do is mix these two modes, which is why it doesn't work.

*Edit:* As others have pointed out, subscripting a `std::string` object can work, so long as the string has been initialised with sufficient capacity. In the case here, the string is empty and therefore all the subscripts are out of bounds.

Comment: some problems in topcoder aks u to pass some specific values so its needed

Answer (score 1):

Going by the definition for the subscript operator on std::string:

```
const char& operator[] ( size_t pos ) const;
      char& operator[] ( size_t pos );
```

Non-const subscripting  is possible. So the following should work fine:

```
std::string a;
a.resize(2);

a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '2';

std::cout << a;
```

Seems like a round-about way to do it though.